# How to debug the debugger of visual studio 2008 when debugging a multi threaded application?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, debugging

That's a hard title, let me explain what I mean, currently I'm programming a multi threaded application, and when I set a breakpoint in my code :

- Sometimes the breakpoint doesn't
  break,
- Sometimes the debugger can't
  evaluate variables,
- Every time, Step by step
  doesn't work as expected (it jumps
  anywhere)

My multi thread app has 2 threads : one is waiting user input at Console.Read(), and the other I want to debug.

A co-worker has the same problem with VS 2008.
Do you know a solution of this annoying problem ?

Thanks in advance for your help !

Comment: Here's a related thread on the subject:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/336628/step-over-when-debugging-multithreaded-programs-in-visual-studio

Comment: That's not the same problem as me, I don't have multiple thread running code, one is waiting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see MS Hotfix: [Updates for Visual Studio 2008 SP1 debugging and breakpoints](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/957912)