# Visual Studio 2008 .Net - Step Over Current Process

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, multithreading, debugging

I try to debug several applications that communicates with each other - and want to have ability to step over without switching to another process/thread.
So Visual Studio has command "Step Over Current Process (Ctrl-Alt-F10)" - which looks like what I want but it's disabled, why?

I've found the same question but for C++:
["Step over" when debugging multithreaded programs in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336628/step-over-when-debugging-multithreaded-programs-in-visual-studio)

So write macros is only way for .net too?

Comment: Perhaps you could use a conditional breakpoint?

Comment: 1) Breakpoints not so usable - too many breakpoints needed if use it instead of "step over"
2) Sometimes I have same code works in different processes - how to define in condition that breakpoint is only for current process?

Comment: Oh it seems I found answer for question 2) - so called Breakpoint Filter is exactly for that, like: ProcessId = 123 or ProcessName=<Your_Process>.

Answer (score 2):

My understanding is there is no real way to do this in visual studio.  Unlike Eclipse :D.  The best you can do is use the Threads debug window to freeze all threads other than the one you want to debug.

As stated in the comments you can also use a conditional break point and set a filter like "ThreadNameToStopOn" == Thread.CurrentThread.Name