# Keep Secondary Threads Running While Debugging With Visual Studio

Tags: c#, multithreading, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, breakpoints

I'm making an application that will send step-over key-presses to Visual Studio to enable it to take screenshots of part of its own code being executed line-by-line.

But it seems when you hit a break-point in your code, ALL threads stop, even ones that haven't hit a break-point. Is there any way around this? Is there some way to get Visual Studio to keep other threads running when I hit a break-point? Or do I have to resort to starting a separate process?

**EDIT:** To clarify, when the breakpoint is hit, I need to have execution stop *only* on the thread that hit the breakpoint. I am *not* looking to have the breakpoint only activate when hit by a certain thread. In other words, I need to have part of my program keep executing while one thread is stopped at a breakpoint in the debugger.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, it seems that whenever you hit a break-point in a process, *all* threads in that process halt, and there doesn't seem to be any way of overriding that behavior. 
The only way to do what I'm trying to do is to create a second `Process`, and have that `Process` be responsible for sending the virtual key-presses to Visual Studio, via an external API call.

Obviously you'll have to have some way of communicating between the main process and the key-pressing process. I looked around and I found that [Anonymous Pipes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb546102(v=vs.100).aspx) are probably the best method for communicating between two processes running on the same machine.

Comment: In fact it is possible to break in a single thread. Windows calls this "SuspendThread", Visual Studio calls it "freeze/thaw"ing, and you've called it halting... Open debug > windows > threads and play around.  Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/6513021/4250150

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old reference and my answer arrive a lot too late but just to let you know... I think it still apply: [You can't debug yourself](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/jmstall/you-cant-debug-yourself)