# How to debug message queue listener in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-debugging, visual-studio-2022

We have couple of [BackgroundService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.backgroundservice?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0) classes listening to message queues. I'm trying to debug a helper function that gets called when an event is read from the queue. Breakpoint is set to the entry point of the function.

Problem:
While I'm debugging, if another event comes in one of the queues, Visual Studio repositions the yellow arrow back to the breakpoint. If I continue hitting F10, the yellow arrow seems to debug both events parallely, as it skips few lines and jumps back few lines.

Comment: Not sure but may be you can check this out   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/how-to-use-the-threads-window?view=vs-2022&tabs=csharp

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5304752/how-to-debug-a-single-thread-in-visual-studio)